# Label Encoding and Imputing Categorical Data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset, encode, categorical-data

I have a dataset with some `catergorical`  columns in it. Some of these columns have missing values indicated by `np.nan` in it.

I want to `LabelEncode` the categorical data and later `Impute` the missing values. I am using `sklearn` for this. But when I try to `LabelEncode` the `categorical` columns like shown below the 'nan' values are treated as a label and it is encoded to some value.

```
for x in cat_cols:
    encoder = LabelEncoder()
    alldata[x] = encoder.fit_transform(alldata[x].astype(str))
```

I don't want this to happen. How can I encode the `categorical` values except `nan`.?

I know I can replace the `nan` with some value and `Encode` that. But I don't want to do that. I want to replace `nan` with `mode` for imputing using the `Imputer` from sklearn. How can I do this.?

Comment: Why not just note the value np.nan is assigned and replace it back to np.nan

Comment: I have many columns to deal with and many data items in it. which will make it complex to keep track.

Comment: @VivekKumar is right, this is the easiest way to do this. You can quickly map the nan values using something like `nan_val = str(encoder.transform(['nan'])[0])` to see what the nan corresponds to in your new array.

Comment: Each column will be handled inside a loop, so keep track of that there. Just do `alldata[x][alldata[x]==nan_val]='nan'` where nan_val is defined by @ncfirth in upper comment

Comment: Thanks it worked.!